# Global variables accessible to other websites opened in same tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, security, firefox

Today I found a security issue with Chrome (or maybe other browsers I haven't tested yet). What happens is that once you open a site and then open another site in the same tab, the previous site's global variables are accessible to the current site in that tab. I have demonstrated it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDFKsLaecOs

Browsers should fix this but is there any other way to protect our global variables?

**This is how you can reproduce it:**

I logged in to exotel.com site and they are using a `name` variable to store currently logged in user's name. You can use it in console and check its value.

Now go to any other site in same tab and try accessing that variable from exotel. Your name will be displayed or just add a button from HTML in inspector and on click of that display the name variable.

Comment: Questions shouldn't depend on external resources to be understood. Tell us how to reproduce the problem here. Don't make us go and watch a video.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsible_disclosure would be worth your time too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the description of `window.name` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

You're renaming the window, not creating a new global variable.

---

> is there any other way to protect our global variables?

Don't assign values to predefined properties unless you really mean it.

Also avoid using global variables in the first place.

When do you need to use global variables, don't make them implicit globals. Declare them using `let` or `const`.

Comment: Ok, that was the name of the window. Thanks for clearing. Other variables are not accessible.